# SHAP DeepExplainer: shap_values containing "nan" values

Tags: tensorflow, shap

I have an issue with my shap values, here is my model:

```
Model: "model_4"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            [(None, 158)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Model)                 (None, 158)          57310       input_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
subtract_4 (Subtract)           (None, 158)          0           input_5[0][0]                    
                                                                 model_1[5][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multiply_4 (Multiply)           (None, 158)          0           subtract_4[0][0]                 
                                                                 subtract_4[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_4 (Lambda)               (None,)              0           multiply_4[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_3 (Reshape)             (None, 1)            0           lambda_4[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 57,310
Trainable params: 57,310
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

And I call :

```
scores = new_model.predict(X_test_scaled)
scores = scores.reshape(scores.shape[0],1)
toexplain = np.append(X_test_scaled, scores, axis = 1)
toexplain = pd.DataFrame(toexplain)
toexplain.sort_values(by = [158], ascending=False, inplace=True)
toexplain = toexplain.iloc[0:16]
toexplain.drop(columns = [158], axis = 1, inplace = True)

explainer=shap.DeepExplainer(new_model, df_sampled_X_train_scaled)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(toexplain, check_additivity=False)
```

But my shap values look like this (for the first instance):

```
shap_values[0]

array([        nan,         nan,         nan,  0.08352888,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,  0.03286453,
               nan,         nan,  0.2984612 ,         nan,         nan,
               nan,  0.01110088, -0.85235232,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan, -0.27935541,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan, -0.18422949,  0.01466912,         nan,
               nan,         nan, -0.1688329 ,  0.07462809,  0.03071906,
               nan, -0.00554245,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,  0.04587848,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,  0.05448143,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,  0.00933742,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,  0.00919492,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan])
```

I'm fairly certain I'm not supposed to have nan values among my shap_values, but I can't seem to find the original issue.
Moreover, the predicted values given by the `shap.force_plot` is different than my model's predictions, which is why I checked my shap_values in the first place.

Would anyone know how could I fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, via reading shap's source code, I realised it didn't take into account that the data were pandas' dataframes, eventhought the documentation says otherwise.

It worked using numpy.arrays